# How should I treat a frangipani?

Tags: flowers, watering, fertilizer, tropical

I've just potted a [frangipani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumeria) (plumeria) cutting given to me by a friend and since it's not in its natural climate, I'm wondering what conditions it will thrive in?  If it matters, I live in a temperate zone.

How should I water it?  How much sun does it need?  Fertiliser?  Does it need to be changed with the seasons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frangipani (*Plumeria*) are tropical plants from the Americas, but have been naturalised to other parts of the world - especially Asia and the Pacific.

So it looks like they need warm weather.

As a tree / shrub, it sounds like outside would be ideal. [GardeningTipsAndIdeas](http://www.gardeningtipsnideas.com/2007/02/how_to_grow_a_frangipani_plant.html) suggest they should be okay in the lower third of the US. So they must have some frost tolerance.

References are Australian but the [SacredGardenFrangipanis.com website](http://www.sacredgardenfrangipanis.com/frangipani_growing_advice.php) has much more useful information, including this snippet:

> How to care for your new Frangipani
>   Plants
>
> Upon receiving your plants, they
>   should be potted up and kept in semi
>   shade or full sun in mornings and
>   shade from midday and afternoon until
>   roots can be seen coming out of bottom
>   of pots.
>
> The ideal potting mix, is 40%
>   commercial potting mix and 60%
>   inorganic material such as course sand
>   or perlite or gravel. Commercial
>   potting mixes are generally full of
>   fungus and bacteria which can be
>   harmful to plants.
>
> Always water plants/potting mix with a
>   systemic fungicide and bactericide
>   when potting up your plants.

Answer (score 8):

They are succulent, and I've seen them thrive in very hot, dry weather (Kona, Hawai`i). If they don't get enough sun or if they get too much water, the plant will be lanky. Use lots of nitrogen rich fertilizer to get them to produce plentiful blooms.